# Getting all messages from android device

Tags: android

I'm using a code to get all the messages from device. It works fine when executing within an activity, but for some reason it's not working when inside a service.

I'm using following code:

```
public class GetMessageData {
Context context;
GetMessageData(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
public JSONObject GetSMSDetails()
{
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONArray jarray = null;
    String link[] = {"content://sms/inbox","content://sms/sent","content://sms/draft"};

    try {

        jarray = new JSONArray();

        result = new JSONObject();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Cursor c= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // Read the sms data and store it in the list
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {

            for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

                result.put("body",c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());

                result.put("date",c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString());
                result.put("read",c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("read")).toString());
                result.put("type",c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString());
                if((c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString()).equals("3"))
                {
                    //Cursor cur= getContentResolver().query("", null, null ,null,null);
                    //startManagingCursor(cur);

                    String threadid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id")).toString();
                    Cursor cur= context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true"), null, "_id ="+threadid ,null,null);
                    startManagingCursor(cur);
                    if(cur.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        String  recipientId = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("recipient_ids")).toString();
                        cur=  context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses"), null, "_id = " + recipientId, null, null);
                        startManagingCursor(cur);
                        if(cur.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                            result.put("address",address);
                            cur.close();
                        }
                    }

                }else
                {
                    result.put("address",c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                }
                jarray.put(result);
                result = new JSONObject();


                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();

        result.put("smslist", jarray);
        //result = new JSONObject(jarray.toString());

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

In this code I'm getting error at `startManagingCursor()`.
Also while searching I found that `startManagingCursor()` is *deprecated*.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I'm getting error as: cannot resolve startManagingCursor(). I tried using context.startManagingCursor() but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

startManagingCursor() method was deprecated in API level 11. Use the new [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) class with [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package.

Check out [this tutorial series](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html).

I read everywhere that the startManagingCursor method is deprecated and you should use the CursorLoader class.
If you are willing to inherit from FragmentActivity, you can use the Loader framework implementation in the Android Support package, going all the way back to Android 1.6.

That being said, "deprecated" in Android usually means "we will continue to support this, but we think there are better solutions". You can certainly use startManagingCursor() on API Level 11+. However, the problems with managed cursors (notably that they requery() on an activity restart on the main application thread) are still there, on older and newer Android versions.

But does that mean that you should use the CursorLoader class even for apps that support API levels < 11?
You certainly can, and, all else being equal, you probably should. However, all else is rarely equal, and the FragmentActivity requirement may be a problem for you.

If you are developing a new application, today, you should be thinking about fragments from the outset, in which case you would be using FragmentActivity anyway, and therefore using Loader should not be a problem.

I don't appear to be able to import the cursor loader class with api 4
The Android Support package implementation of Loader works on API Level 4 and above.